# How to iterate through a tuple containing class objects?

Tags: python, object, tuples

I am currently working on a piece of code that will automate a process for engineering software (Orcaflex) that I use on daily basis. I am using python to interface with Orcaflex to run catenary calculations automatically. My code is below along with the output for reference.

My idea is to grab all of the objects in the Orcaflex model and iterate through that tuple object to pull out the line names to feed that data into Orcaflex's line wizard tool. The objects type is a tuple, but when I index that tuple I get back a type of (class 'OrcFxAPI.OrcaFlexObject').

My question is how do I iterate through this tuple containing objects so that I can obtain the Line name string? Any help would greatly be appreciated.

**Update**: I was able to convert the object to a string and perform basic string operations to grab the line names. Please see my updated code below. However, a more efficient way of grabbing the line names from the model can be seen in my second post using dot notation to get the line name and type.

My updated code:

```
# Created by: Brian Weber
# Created on: 09/15/2015

# This script will load a base file and then calculate for
# different tensions using the line setup wizard.

# Note that buoys are modeled as clump attachments on the line with a global offset for
# pennant wire.

import OrcFxAPI
import numpy as np

def convert_MT_to_kN(value_in_MT):
    g = 9.80665002864
    value_in_kN = value_in_MT * g
    return value_in_kN

g = 9.80665002864

# Load file name
filename = 'CX15-Anchor Plan.dat'
model = OrcFxAPI.Model(filename)

# Pipe tensions to be solved for; units are in MT then converted to kN for Orcaflex
min_tension = float(raw_input("\n Please enter the minimum tension to calculate catenary in MT: "))
max_tension = float(raw_input("\n Please enter the maximum tension to calculate catenary in MT: "))
tension_increment = float(raw_input("\n Please enter the tension increment to calculate catenary in MT: "))
pipe_tensions = (np.arange(min_tension, max_tension, tension_increment) * g).tolist()

# Grab lines in model
lines = []
objects = model.objects # returns a tuple
# Convert objects to strings
for o in objects:
    o_string = repr(o)
    if "Line:" in o_string:
        string_split = o_string.split("'")
        lines.append(string_split[1])

# Solve all lines in model for all line tensions
print('\nSolving line tensions...')
for tension in pipe_tensions:
    print('\nLine tension being solved for is {:.2f} kN.\n').format(tension)
    for line in lines:
        model.general.LineSetupCalculationMode = 'Calculate Line Lengths'
        model[line].LineSetupIncluded = 'Yes'
        # model.general.LineSetupMinDamping = 5
        # model.general.LineSetupMaxDamping = 20
        # model.general.LineSetupMaxIterations = 50
        model[line].LineSetupTargetVariable = 'Tension'
        model[line].LineSetupTargetValue = tension
        model[line].LineSetupLineEnd = 'End A'
        print('Line {} set.').format(line)
    print('\nInvoking Line Setup Wizard...')
    model.InvokeLineSetupWizard()   
    print('\nLine Setup Wizard done.')
    # Calculate static position of mooring lines and buoys
    model.CalculateStatics()
    # Save static simulation and load into new object
    model.SaveSimulation(('{} - {:.2f} kN.sim').format(filename, tension))

print('\nLine Wizard has completed!')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found another, more efficient way to grab the line names from the Orcaflex model. Since objects returns a tuple of class objects, you can use dot notation to get the type (**line.type** which returns an integer) and name (**line.name** which returns a string) by using the following code:

```
import OrcFxAPI
import numpy as np

g = 9.80665002864

# Load file name
filename = 'CX15-Anchor Plan.dat'
model = OrcFxAPI.Model(filename)

# Pipe tensions to be solved for; units are in MT then converted to kN for Orcaflex
min_tension = float(raw_input("\n Please enter the minimum tension to calculate catenary in MT: "))
max_tension = float(raw_input("\n Please enter the maximum tension to calculate catenary in MT: "))
tension_increment = float(raw_input("\n Please enter the tension increment to calculate catenary in MT: "))
pipe_tensions = (np.arange(min_tension, max_tension, tension_increment) * g).tolist()

# Grab lines in model
objects = model.objects # returns a tuple
lines = [obj for obj in objects if obj.type == OrcFxAPI.otLine] # All line objects in model

# Solve all lines in model for all line tensions
print('\nSolving line tensions...')
for tension in pipe_tensions:
    print('\nLine tension being solved for is {:.2f} kN.\n').format(tension)
    for line in lines:
        model.general.LineSetupCalculationMode = 'Calculate Line Lengths'
        model[line.name].LineSetupIncluded = 'Yes'
        model[line.name].LineSetupTargetVariable = 'Tension'
        model[line.name].LineSetupTargetValue = tension
        model[line.name].LineSetupLineEnd = 'End A'
        print('Line {} set.').format(line.name)
    print('\nInvoking Line Setup Wizard...')
    model.InvokeLineSetupWizard()   
    print('\nLine Setup Wizard done.')
    # Calculate static position of mooring lines and buoys
    model.CalculateStatics()
    # Save static simulation and load into new object
    model.SaveSimulation(('{} - {:.2f} kN.sim').format(filename, tension))

print('\nLine Wizard has completed!')
```

Answer (score -1):

What are the contents of the object within the tuple you get back? Do you know this object's location in the tuple? do those objects have the property you want? So as an example , if the object is the second elem in tuple you could do:

```
objects[1].<<func_name_you_are_interested_in>>()
or 
objects[1].<<property_name_you_are_interested_in>>
```

Can you give a sample content of objects variable in your example? (by printing it)

Comment: If you click on the last link in my original post, there's a picture of the objects variable output and the type of an index of the objects variable.

Comment: @JTurk: Use comments to ask questions.

Comment: Would you mind to explain the downvote?At least I know what I did wrong!

Comment: @flamenco: what r u talking about? u r the one who downvoted me on this?

Comment: @JTurk that was exactly what I needed. I was able to convert the object to a string, tell if "Line:" was in the string then split the single quotes to grab the line name. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @Brian: if you found "another better" way to solve this, i'm fine if you unaccepted my solution and accepted your own..but why on earth did you down-vote me? its not like my solution was invalid or "not helpful" which is why people get downvoted...

Comment: @JTurk I didn't down vote you. If anything I would up vote your answer, but I can't since I don't have 15 reputation points yet.